# Encrypting data on PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, encryption

I'm running some queries using PostgreSQL for student  purposes. Now I need to encrypt some fields using AES256 to run the same queries and compare the times. Any idea how this can be done using UPDATE table? For example, I need to encrypt the customer address of the table address. Can I do this using UPDATE? Can anyone give me an example? Couldn't find anything online. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can do that with an UPDATE - you just need to find the correct encryption function you want to use. A good starting point is probably [pgcrypto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I read the documentation but honesty I didn't understand how to use the AES256 function on a UPDATE statement.

Comment: Something along the lines: `update the_table set the_column = pgp_sym_encrypt(the_column, 'some secret passphrase', 'compress-algo=1, cipher-algo=aes256')`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that returns me "ERROR: value too long for type character(20); Should i change to TEXT type?

Comment: That simply means the encrypted value is longer than 20 character. Yes you will need to increase the size of that column. `text` won't impose any length restrictions

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name. If I try to see the data of that column after the encryption do I need to use pgp_sym_decrypt?

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto;

    INSERT INTO table(name,age) VALUES(
    PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT('John', 'AES_KEY'),
    PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT('22', 'AES_KEY')
    );

    UPDATE table SET
    (name,age) = (
    PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT('Jona', 'AES_KEY'),
    PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT('15','AES_KEY')
    ) WHERE id='1';

    SELECT
      PGP_SYM_DECRYPT(name::bytea, 'AES_KEY') as name
      PGP_SYM_DECRYPT(age::bytea, 'AES_KEY') as age
    FROM table WHERE(
      LOWER(PGP_SYM_DECRYPT(name::bytea, 'AES_KEY')
      LIKE LOWER('%John%')
    );
```

Comment: Do I have to encrypt each row manually? Because the data of the table was generated and I have like 10.000 rows.

Comment: accidently posted it too soon, sorry guys

Comment: Thank you @MontėČiuklys. In your example you use 'Jona' and '15'. I suppose that's one row of the table, right?

Comment: @Guilherme You could choose more rows with WHERE arguments, but the data encrypted on all of those would still be JONA and 15, yes.

Comment: @MontėČiuklys I'm asking because i have too many rows to update them one by one.

Comment: @Guilherme try switching Jona and 15 with the column names, and then include something like WHERE ID NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5) which will chose all of the rows whose ID is not 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: @Guilherme in other comments i saw you had "ERROR: value too long for type character(20)" your sql row type should be able to contain bigger values.

Comment: I did this `update the_table set the_column = pgp_sym_encrypt(the_column, 'some secret passphrase', 'compress-algo=1, cipher-algo=aes256')` and changed the column type to TEXT and I think it's working. At least it is updating. Is this procedure wrong?

Comment: @Guilherme I wrote it as an example you should flex it to your own use. Use google to see if the encryption is the same as the encrypted values in your rows. If its the same it worked!

Comment: I will. Thank you!